# Rollback / Undo on Neo4j Community 2.3.2?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, rollback

How do I undo / rollback last query on Neo4j community 2.3.2?

I know it might be a simple question,but I've recently started using Neo4j and query languages. Though I've found another post with a similar question, the answer wasn't clear for me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to rollback a query that has been completed. There is no undo.

You can cancel a Cypher query submitted via the Neo4j browser, **while it's still running**, using the *Cancel and Close* icon on the top right of the area for said query.

You can also cancel a query wrapped in a transaction if it hasn't been completed/commited yet. This is actually the mechanism used by the Neo4j Browser described above.

Comment: That's disappointing. How can you handle the responsability of not being able to make any mistake? :p

Comment: It's common to most database systems I know. Undos are implemented at the transaction level to ensure consistency. Depending on the mistake there are options: fix dataset to undo mistake, recover last backup before (with implied data loss). Some systems/services implement point-in-time rollback, so you might be able to go back to the point in time just before you executed the query, but you would lose all queries that happened later.

Comment: We've got a beta version of an Audit module that will soon allow rollback (or, more generally, time travel). However, it will only work with Enterprise Edition. It stores the details about every tx within the graph, so rollback will be preformed by executing a compensating transaction. For more info - info (at) graphaware (dot) com

Comment: Bless you... (just typed massive DELETE into the wrong browser... ) phew..